# Perform task in destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

Is it a good technique to perform important/critical tasks of an object in the destructor?
Such as:

```
class MyObject{
  ~MyObject() {
    Execute();
  }
  void Execute() {...}
};
```

Comment: It depends what the task is and if it can throw exceptions

Comment: Additionally you should not call any functions on 'this' that are virtual from a dtor

Comment: Agree with the above. One critical thing is: you cannot throw exceptions in destructors, only one can be handled at a time. Otherwise: crash

Comment: @Pete Why should virtual member calls be avoided in the destructor?

Comment: @Codor: because they'll be dispatched to the implementation of the function in `MyObject`, not to any override that there might be in a derived class of `MyObject`. By the time `~MyObject` is executed, the derived class destructor has already been executed, so C++ takes away that particular mechanism to call functions of the derived class. It's probably possible to come up with a situation where making the call and letting it dispatch to the base class is correct and principled, but if you can find that situation then you're smart enough to know to ignore the rule of thumb "don't do it" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Destructors* are meant to be a way to automatically clean up resources held by an object when it goes out-of- scope. Nothing else should be done in *destructor*. But the clean up may involve critical or complex processing. Also make sure exception does not leave your destructor. That will lead to *terminate* your program unexpectedly if the *destrcutor was originally called because of stack unwinding due to another exception*.

It is good practice to provide public interface for critical clean-up/resource management, so that client code can call it and handle if any exception arises. You can check if the clean up process is done in the destructor, if not perform it, but **swallow any exception thrown**.

To summarize, it is **NOT** a good practice to perform anything at all (whether critical or not) other than resource clean up in destructor.

Comment: I would note that "resource clean-up with complex processing" for example includes things like "committing a transaction" or more generally "flushing the output". From the POV of the data storage you're using this is more than just releasing resources (indeed it might involve allocating resources, which is one reason why you might need to swallow an exception). But from the POV of the user of your class it's clean-up if they're happy with making a best-effort to succeed, and not just clean-up (hence they should use the other interface) if they need to respond to failure.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the answer is NO. E.g. if the program crashes, destructor won't be called. There're other circumstances when dtor isn't called. Destructor is dedicated method for clean up. Class users expect such behavior.

Comment: That depends upon your definition of 'important/critical tasks'.  std::vector freeing memory in its destructor is something I would consider a critical task.

Comment: If the entire program crashes, then freeing memory is irrelevant. The OS will do that upon process termination. But not every exception leads to an application crash. It could be caught elsewhere by code, handled, and execution resumed. So destructors do need to at least try and prevent memory leaks.